# Best way to read error messages from a Log4Net log file

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, error-logging

I would like to display the log created by Log4Net on a web page in my admin interface.

Isnt there any methods available in the log4net library to read the error messages from the configured source (textfile or database)? At the moment I am using a database table to log all errors.
If not, there must be some third party libraries available that does this for me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an elegant solution to collect and search logs using log4net based logging, a syslog daemon like kiwi syslog in combination with log4net local or remote syslog appender would probably be the easiest way to do it. Logging in a database works, but in my opinion logs are of no concern to the application itself and should be kept away from it. For instance a failing database connection would probably not show up if the logs resided solely on the same database.

Comment: Thanks, I totaly agree with you! We are using logging in database during developement, to make things easier.
I still thinks it is very strange that there is no easier solution or any library available to read log files created by log4net.